# How can I share a video during a meeting in BlueJeans?

Tags: windows, bluejeans

I use [BlueJeans](https://www.bluejeans.com/) 2.5.2270 for videoconference on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

On https://adobe.bluejeans.com/videos/ I see:

> Videos can be shared during a meeting

[image]

I assume they don't mean sharing one's screen and playing the video.

How can I share a video during a meeting in BlueJeans?

I don't see any obvious way to do so in the BlueJeans desktop client:

[image]

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Is  "meeting in BlueJeans" some kind of English idiom? I couldn't find it Googling for it.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I wonder how they chose this name :/

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I have received dozens of downvotes on superuser for perfectly fine questions, and hundreds on all Stack Exchange websites… I think it's just part of using Internet  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the tech support (private Slack):

> BlueJeans is currently working on how to implement the  video share in the 2.5 version of BlueJeans. It is on their roadmap but we do not have a release date on this feature yet.